# Swapping from ASP .Net Core 1.0.0-rc2-final to 1.0.0 causes published site to fail

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

I've just upgraded my ASP project from ASP .Net Core 1.0.0-rc2-final to 1.0.0. There were two issues that were not handled by the Nuget Package Manager.

Firstly

```json
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

was updated to just

```json
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0",
```

which failed to compile and so I changed that to

```json
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

Secondly I needed to change

```csharp
services.AddMvc();
```

to

```csharp
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

in my `Startup.cs` file. The only other changes were those made by Nuget to my `project.json` file.

The project runs without issue locally, and successfully publishes from VS2015 to Azure. However, when I open a browser onto my site on Azure I get the error message

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Why? How do I diagnose and fix this error?

(N.B. Following @Pawel's suggestion below my `web.config`, `project.json`, and `Startup.cs` are available in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/dumbledad/d86875638be358fad0b4b0c7fc5f27d9).)

Comment: Show your project.json, StartUp and web.config *after* you published your app. You can also take a look at troubleshooting steps I showed in my blog post: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Comment: From the Azure VM it's published to?

Comment: yes. because if it's incorrect the application won't be started by proxy/antares/iis

Comment: The `config.json` files are identical on each deployment (the RC2 one that works and the 1.0 one that fails with the CGI error). They just have keys and the connection string in. I cannot find the `project.json` file on either deployment. The `web.config` file is the same on each, and I've posted it [here](https://gist.github.com/dumbledad/d86875638be358fad0b4b0c7fc5f27d9).

Comment: I cannot find `Startup.cs` in either deployment either. It gets compiled, right?

Comment: No - they are not the same! The RC2 `web.config` in `D:\home\site\wwwroot` has `%DNX_PATH%` and `%DNX_ARGS%` replaced with values. The one I was looking at was in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot`. But in 1.0 they have the `%` variables in still. Why? Is there something different in the post-publish replacement script between RC2 and 1.0?

Comment: You don't seem to have postpublish script (publish-iis) configured properly. Show you project.json file. Read again the post I sent a link to. It contains the details - or create a ASP.Net Core app and compare project.json files.

Comment: I have added the `project.json` file to [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/dumbledad/d86875638be358fad0b4b0c7fc5f27d9), and it has the unchanged post-publish script in (similar to the one in your bog post). I agree that the evidence point to it not working, but I don't see how to fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your tools section is empty. There is a bug in NuGet UI that when you try to update tools packages it will move them to the `dependencies` and the tools will stop working (https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/215#issuecomment-229433836). In your case because you don't have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISIntegration.Tools` in the `tools` section the postpublish script doesn't do its job - it does not update the web.config. (You actually should see some messages when you publish your app). You need to fix your `project.json` to put tools in the right place (note that some tools actually need entries in both - `tools` and `dependencies`). Here is a project.json file created when you create a new web app in VS:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

Make sure that tools (packages with the `.Tools` suffix) in your project.json are in the same locations as in the snippet above.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't empty that section, NuGet did as it updated the packages. In any case this works. I use the "tools" section you give, update the NuGet packages (I choose to include pre-releases) and now it runs locally and deployed in azure. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix that. Yes, this NuGet UI issue is a problem.

Comment: It looks like to get it to build on a new machine I need to additionally edit the top level `global.json` file and change `"version": "1.0.0-preview1-002702"` to `"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"`. No idea why they were not updated automatically, nor why it still has an "preview" value after release, but I wanted to record my additional step here.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing - runtime is RTM but tooling is preview2. Yes you do need to update sdk in the global.json - this is one of the first things mentioned in the migration doc: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc2-to-rtm.html?highlight=migrate